# How to convert array to valid json

Tags: javascript, json, object

Good day. How can I convert this using javascript

```
{Apple: 134, Orange: 223, Peaches: 143}
```

to

```
["Apple", "134"], ["Orange", "223"], ["Peaches", "143"]
```

Comment: the data structure is not valid for JS.

Comment: Hmm that doesn't look right, `[Apple: 134, Orange: 223, Peaches: 143]` uses the `[]` of an array but looks more like an object. Should it be `{Apple: 134, Orange: 223, Peaches: 143}` instead

Comment: This isn't valid json,valid json woule be : `[{"Apple":134},{"Orange":223},{"Peaches":143]` or in a single object : `{"Apple":134,"Orange":223,"Peaches":143}`

Comment: asking array and json format is not valid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant `{Apple: 134, Orange: 223, Peaches: 143};`

since an array doesn't have `:` as seperator.

try

```
var obj = {Apple: 134, Orange: 223, Peaches: 143};
var output = Object.keys(obj).map( function(key){
  return [ key, obj[key] ]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this `var jsonString = JSON.stringify(obj);`

This works in the modern browsers